# I am trying to write some file in binary, where I need to overwrite the file contents, how to over write instead of inserting

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles, ofstream

I am writing a binary file in C++, where I traverse to a particular location and need to over-write the contents with the new one. I know the contents of the integer size, so I keep track of the location and over write it. Seems like, ofstream write function inserts or appends the variable. Is there a way, where I can over write, instead of appending or inserting in a file

```
  long word = sizeof(int) + sizeof(long) + sizeof(long);

 std::ofstream file_write(filename, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

 file_write.seekp(word);      
 long pos = file_write.tellp();
 file_write.write((char *)&some_integer,sizeof(int));
 file_write.close()

 //some other location

 file_write.seekp(pos);
 file_write.write((char *)&some_other_integer,sizeof(int));
```

//Here some_integer should be over written by some_other_integer. Is there a way to do it?

That will be like

value1,value2,value3

I might be able to replace value 2 with value 5.

then it should look like

value1,value5,value3

Comment: If you're just trying to overwrite a single value in the file, the code you've shown will work.  Are you sure that the code you've shown is actually representative of the code you're using?  Are you sure that the code is not working?

Comment: AM sorry, I guess it works that way, you are right, I got confused, with a different problem. Sorry for the post guys, is there a way to delete the post?

Comment: Hey Eric, its not working that way. I deletes the information before it and pushes the information after it. Refer this link for more code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096196/cant-over-write-on-a-specific-location-on-a-file-over-write-on-a-specific-loca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `std::ios::trunc` to your open parameters, as in:

```
std::ofstream file_write(filename, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary|std::ios::trunc);
```

That will truncate the file, discarding any existing content.

Comment: What does truncate do? Sounds dangerous though. I hope it over writes the exact content location not any more insert the values in between.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  truncating the file will erase all the content of the file, which is probably _not_ what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

the relevant flag is truncate

> (truncate) Any current content is discarded, assuming a length of
>   zero on opening.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out. We need to use fstream instead of ofstream. Thanks for you help everyone