# Can't Over write on a specific location on a file. Over write on a specific location deletes all the contents before it and moves the value after it

Tags: c++, fstream, random-access

In my project, there is a need to read and write to binary file, basically serializing linked lists in a file, where I store the value in binary format and remember the tellp()/tellg() offset, how ever, I cannot do that. That erases all the contents in it to zero and instead of inserting it pushes the current content back.

For Example, in the below program, I open a file, write values say 1,120,323. Then close it and read it, it shows the exact correct values 1,120,323. But When I try to replace the value of 120->220, 1 becomes zero and the value read as 0 220 220. Basically 220 over writes and pushes 323 back.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  std::cout<<"File Ofstream Testing "<<std::endl;   

  const char * file_name = "Test_File.bin";
  int ONE = 1;
  int ZERO = 0;

  int ONE_TWENTY = 120;
  int TWO_TWENTY = 220;

  int THREE_TWENTY_THREE = 323;
  int THREE_FORTY_FIVE = 345;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
 std::ofstream file_write(file_name, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

 if(!(file_write.is_open())) {
    std::cout<<"File cannot be opened "<<std::endl;
    exit(0);
 }

 file_write.seekp(0);
 file_write.write((char *)&ONE,sizeof(int));
 file_write.write((char *)&ONE_TWENTY,sizeof(int));
 file_write.write((char *)&THREE_TWENTY_THREE,sizeof(int));

 file_write.close();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
 std::ifstream file_read(file_name,std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

 if(!(file_read.is_open())) {
        std::cout<<"File cannot be opened "<<std::endl;
        exit(0);
 }

 int temp;
 file_read.seekg(0);
 file_read.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(int));
 std::cout<<"Temp "<<temp<<std::endl;
 file_read.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(int));
 std::cout<<"Temp "<<temp<<std::endl;
 file_read.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(int));
 std::cout<<"Temp "<<temp<<std::endl;

 file_read.close();
}
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  std::ofstream file_write(file_name, std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

  if(!(file_write.is_open())) {
   std::cout<<"File cannot be opened "<<std::endl;
   exit(0);
 }

 file_write.seekp(sizeof(int));
 file_write.write((char *)&TWO_TWENTY,sizeof(int));
 file_write.seekp(sizeof(int) + sizeof(int));
 file_write.write((char *)&THREE_FORTY_FIVE,sizeof(int));

 file_write.close();
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
  std::ifstream file_read(file_name,std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);

  if(!(file_read.is_open())) {
    std::cout<<"File cannot be opened "<<std::endl;
    exit(0);
}

  int temp;
  file_read.seekg(0);
  file_read.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(int));
  std::cout<<"Temp "<<temp<<std::endl;
  file_read.seekg(sizeof(int));
  file_read.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(int));
  std::cout<<"Temp "<<temp<<std::endl;
  file_read.seekg(sizeof(int) + sizeof(int));
  file_read.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(int));
  std::cout<<"Temp "<<temp<<std::endl;

   file_read.close();
 }
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 return 0;
}//fn:main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For output streams, opening with `std::ios::out` is equivalent to `std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc`, so when you declare `std::ofstream file_write` for the second time, the previously written content gets discarded and you're writing the file anew. When you then do `file_write.seekp(sizeof(int));` on an empty stream, zero bytes are written.
   If you needed to append to an `ofstream` then you would open it with `std::ios:app`. That wouldn't truncate the file, but it would only let you append to it on the other hand.

If you want to do random-access writing on an file stream, you need to declare it as `fstream` and open it in both reading and writing mode. So what you need is:

`std::fstream file_write(file_name, std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);`

Comment: Actually I tried to open file in fstream, as you mentioned, but everytime it says file cannot be opened, when I check for file.is_open(). Is there a problem in the way I open?

Comment: std::fstream file(file_name,std::ios::in|std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);

        if(!file.is_open()) {
                std::cout<<"Cannot Open File, Exiting.... "<<std::endl;
                exit(0);
        }

Comment: I tried it, and it works. I get 1, 220, 345 as output. Make sure the previous streams are closed before you try to open same file with another stream.

Comment: Actually I wrote a opened a new file. I still have the problem

Comment: The problem is I cannot open the file itself. ifstream, ofstream works, but not with fstream.

Comment: Hey it works, I guess I cannot open a file with fstream for the first time, Am I right???? Thanks a lot...... :) :) :) :)

Comment: @howtechstuffworks You're right, opening a non-existing file for reading will always fail.